# Properties file in the Spring MVC application throwing FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services

I have a Spring application and there is a context XML file created with a reference to a file in local file system -

```
<context:property-placeholder
        location="file:///${ENV_VAR}PropsFile.properties" />
```

When i am trying to run this web application, i am continously getting FileNotFoundException, and in the same terminal from which i am trying to run Tomcat using

```
sudo catalina.sh jpda start
```

if i do echo $ENV_VAR, its showing the right path. I have already set the chmod of the directory to 777.

This application is working fine on my local windows environment, local Cnetos VM, however issue is coming up in Amazon AWS instance.

----------------Below issue is no more ocuuring--------------

----------------However above issue is still there-----------

In fact just realized that a simple  -

```
input = new FileInputStream(System.getenv("ENV_VAR") + "PropsFile.properties");
```

is returning file not found exception like nullPropsFile.properties.

Any suggestion what can be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Try creating a file instead of reading one. With any luck a new file will get created and you'll be able to tell what went wrong. My persoanl guess: missing slash at end of ENV_VAR

Comment: Can you tell ENV_VAR value given?

Comment: It was a directory path like /home/user/location/folderName/

Answer (score 0):

Removed the sudo from the command to start the catalina jpda and it worked fine.